# Javascript Video Capture

Tags: javascript, video, p5.js

I have the following code. It displays filter video at top and original video at bottom.

How to hide the video at the top?

Thanks

```
// https://editor.p5js.org/

function setup() {
   createCanvas(320, 260);
   video = createCapture(VIDEO);
   video.size(width,height);
 }
 let video;
 function draw() {
 image(video,0,0,width,height);
 // filter(THRESHOLD); 
//  filter(GRAY);
filter(INVERT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [documenation page](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCapture), it says to do `video.hide()` to hide the webcam capture.

And if you don't want the filter, then don't call `filter(...)`

So your code will look like this:

```js
let video;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 260);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(width, height);
  video.hide();
}

function draw() {
  image(video,0,0,width,height);
  // rest of code
}
```

If you ever want to reshow the original video, just run `video.show()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Instead of hiding the video at bottom(original) I want to hide the film negative video.

Comment: Revised code (hiding not yet done)

Comment: let video;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 394);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(width, height);
}

function draw() {
  image(video,0,0,width,height);
  // filter(THRESHOLD); 
  // filter(GRAY);
  filter(INVERT);
}

Comment: Reference https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-pixels.html

Comment: @Paramasivan Ok updated my answer to what you want

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Samathingamajig

The following Code works for me.

```
let video;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 260);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(width, height);
  video.hide();
}

function draw() {
  image(video,0,0,width,height);
  // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we redefine it as below?

```
// https://editor.p5js.org/

function setup() {
   createCanvas(700, 394);
   video = createCapture(VIDEO);
   
   video.hide();
  // video.show();
 }
 let video;
 function draw() {
 image(video,0,0,width,height);
 // filter(THRESHOLD); 
 //  filter(GRAY);
 // filter(INVERT);
}
```